# Как изменить и преобразовать значение в строке в столбце DataFrame?

Tags: python, строки, pandas, dataframe

Дана таблица:

```
import pandas as pd 
df3 = pd.DataFrame({'Name':['020245D5Z022/55D0',  '92014947Q62500/29', '02025727Y052D0/55', '320247528043/01S0'], 'Sum': [80, 100, 200, 300]}) 
print(df3)
```

1. Если '/' на 12 позиции в значении, тогда нужно удалить и получить `020245D5Z02255D0`.
2. А если '/' на 14 позиции в значении, тогда нужно `92014947Q62500/29` преобразовать иначе, левые 11 символов + правые два символа + два символа на позиция 15 и 16", т.е. в нашем случае это `92014947Q6252900`.

```
df3.loc[df3.Name.str[12] == '/']
df3.loc[df3.Name.str[14] == '/']
```

Ответ, должен получиться такой:

```
                Name  Sum
0  020245D5Z02255D0   80
1  92014947Q6252900  100
2  02025727Y05255D0  200
3  32024752804301S0  300
```

Answer (score 3):

```
import numpy as np

df3["Name"] = np.where(df3["Name"].str[12] == "/", 
                       df3["Name"].str.replace("/", "", regex=False), 
                       df3["Name"].str.replace(r"(.+)(.{2})/(.+)", r"\1\3\2"))
```

---

результат:

```
In [47]: df3
Out[47]:
               Name  Sum
0  020245D5Z02255D0   80
1  92014947Q6252900  100
2  02025727Y05255D0  200
3  32024752804301S0  300
```

Answer (score 2):

Вероятно, как-нибудь так:

```
mask1 = df3["Name"].str.find("/") == 12
mask2 = df3["Name"].str.find("/") == 14
df3.loc[mask1, "Name"] = df3.loc[mask1, "Name"].str.replace("/","")
df3.loc[mask2, "Name"] = df3.loc[mask2, "Name"].replace(to_replace="(.+)(.{2})/(.+)", value=r"\1\3\2", regex=True)
```

Результат:

```
               Name  Sum
0  020245D5Z02255D0   80
1  92014947Q6252900  100
2  02025727Y05255D0  200
3  32024752804301S0  300
```

Comment: @katty_data, чтобы поблагодарить автора ответа можно [проголосовать за ответ (для этого необходимо иметь минимум 15 репутационных балов)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/173400/348814) и/или [принять ответ как правильный](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/348814)